# How to create a stopwatch lap time function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time, stopwatch

I am trying to create a stopwatch app that displays lap times. Currently I have it displaying the time when the lap button is clicked. However, I want to display the difference between time a and time b, time b and time c and so forth.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

I have looked at different responses on various blogs and stack overflow but haven't found one I fully understood. So I didn't want to just copy code.

I have included a snippet of the code I believe to be relative to the problem.

```js
const timer = document.getElementById("stopwatch");
const startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");

let lapNumber = 0;

let [hour, min, sec, centisecond] = [0, 0, 0, 0];

let stopTime = true;

let [lapHour, lapMin, lapSec, lapCentiSec] = [0, 0, 0, 0];

function startTimer() {
  if (startButton.innerText === "Start") {
    startButton.innerText = "Stop";
    stopTime = false;
    timerCycle();
  } else if (startButton.innerText === "Stop") {
    startButton.innerText = "Start";
    stopTime = true;
  }
}

function timerCycle() {
  if (stopTime === false) {
    // Set timings to numbers
    centisecond = parseInt(centisecond);
    sec = parseInt(sec);
    min = parseInt(min);
    hour = parseInt(hour);

    centisecond = centisecond + 1;

    if (centisecond == 100) {
      sec = sec + 1;
      centisecond = 0;
    }

    if (sec === 60) {
      min = min + 1;
      sec = 0;
    }

    if (min === 60) {
      hour = hour + 1;
      min = 0;
      sec = 0;
    }
    if (centisecond < 10 || centisecond === 0) {
      centisecond = "0" + centisecond;
    }

    if (sec < 10 || sec === 0) {
      sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    if (min < 10 || min === 0) {
      min = "0" + min;
    }
    if (hour < 10 || hour === 0) {
      hour = "0" + hour;
    }
    timer.innerHTML = `${hour}:${min}:${sec}:${centisecond}`;

    setTimeout("timerCycle()", 10);
  }
}

function lapTime() {
  lapNumber++;
  const lapTimes = `${lapNumber}:  ${timer.innerHTML}`;

  setLocalStorage("laps", lapTimes);
}

function setLocalStorage(key, data) {
  const lapTimes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];
  lapTimes.push(data);
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(lapTimes));
  displayLaps(lapTimes);
}

function displayLaps(lapTimes) {
  const lapContainer = document.querySelector("#lapList");
  const laps = document.createElement("li");
  laps.className = "lap-time";
  if (timer.innerHTML === "00:00:00:00") {
    laps.innerHTML = "Please press start.";
    lapContainer.appendChild(laps);
    return;
  } else {
    const pressStart = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("lap-time"));
    pressStart.forEach((text) => {
      if (text.innerHTML === "Please press start.") {
        text.remove();
      }
    });
  }
  lapTimes.forEach((lapTime) => {
    laps.innerHTML = lapTime;
  });
  lapContainer.appendChild(laps);
}
```

Comment: Using centisecond = centisecond + 1; in a setTimeout with a 10 ms interval isn't going to work. setTimeout is not precise and doesn't account for how long it takes to run your code. Instead just use new Date() to get the current time rather than trying incrementally calculate it.

Comment: Not to mention timer throttling.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with all those centisecsonds etc.
Just get the number of millsecs of the current time when 'Start' is clicked

```
let d = new Date();
let start_ms = d.valueOf();
```

then do the same again when 'Stop' is clicked, and subtract the values to find the milisecs elapsed. Then convert to readable hours, mins secs for the user.